# Python subprocess: How to output instantly and save output and error to a file?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am writing a little Python script to log the output and error of another Python program, and simultaneously print them on my screen as usual. This code works well, except it buffers output of the subprocess python program and output them together once for a long time, instead of printing instantly as usual:

```
subprocess.run(f"python {args.launch} 2>&1 | tee -a {file_path}", shell=True)
```

in which `args.lunch` is the name of my python program and `file_path` is the log file. I have tried some existing solutions but none works for me.

Comment: try running the script with `python -u $yourscript` or set enviroment variable PYTHONUNBUFFERED  and see if it helps..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @rasjani, one way around this is to use the `-u` flag

```python
subprocess.run(f"python -u {args.launch} 2>&1 | tee -a {file_path}", shell=True)
```

I don't have a good explanation for why this works.

---

edit - edited to remove incorrect second option

Comment: Google "output buffering". The OS buffers output when it goes into a pipe for performance reasons, so instead of writing every few bytes as soon as they arrive, it waits for an I/O buffer to fill up before writing anything. This is an extremely common FAQ and the rationale for the `-u` option.

Comment: The "alternatively" part is completely wrong. You are passing `'2>&1'`, `'|'`, `'tee'` etc as arguments to `python`. If you want to use shell features like redirection or pipes, you need a shell. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks a lot for your explanation, which solves all my doubts.

Comment: @FiddleStix Thanks a lot and the first solution works. As what tripleee says, the second dose not save anything, though it can output instantly. Does anybody know why the second can make output instant?

Comment: Presumably `args.launch` ignores the spurious arguments. But that means `tee` doesn't get run at all, nor is any redirection taking place, so neither is there any pipe, and so no output buffering.

Comment: @tripleee I'm aware of what output buffering is but I'd be curious on your thoughts about a) how Python knows whether it is being called interactively or not and b) why a bash program (i.e. a bash script with an echo, a sleep and another echo) does not buffer when Python does.

Comment: Generally, it's the OS which decides whether to buffer or not. What exactly each shell does in this situation is probably too broad a topic to fit into this comment, but if you see them not buffer when attached to a pipe, chances are they explicitly select unbuffered output.